# SaltStack is not starting services

Tags: salt-stack

I need to run service, here's code snippet for that:

```
/etc/init.d/collect-node:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://scripts/collect_node.sh.j2
    - template: jinja
    - mode: 755

  service.running:
    - name: collect-node
    - enable: True
    - restart: True
    - watch:
      - file.managed: /etc/collect/node-config.json
      - file.managed: /etc/init.d/collect-node
    - require:
      - service.running: xvfb
      - user.present: collect
```

The node is managing by vagrant. So when I'm `vagrant up node` it's calling `state.highstate` but service is not running, but when I'm explicitly calling salt-call `state.highstate` in the console, the service starts to run.

What might be problem here? How I can diagnose the problem? Thanks

Comment: Does /var/log/salt/minion have anything useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in dependencies, if other package, script or something is not ready yet then it silently won't run service.

That's why when all stuff are installed the `state.highstate` runs the service.